# how to put the value of a field to null in a csv file in Talend

Tags: talend, isnull

I have a csv file with multiple fields and millions of records. For example in the "Total flight time" field I have several "NA" values. How I do to replace these values by "null" using tMap component?

I want that in my output file,"NA" values appear like "null" so that field "Total flight time" can be type "Int"

Answer (score 0):

you can use tReplace component.
https://help.talend.com/display/TalendComponentsReferenceGuide54EN/tReplace

you should put in Search column "NA" and in Replace with null

Comment: Or you can use a tMap component and in output add this expression : row1.Total_flight_time == "NA" ? null : row1.Total_flight_time

Answer (score 0):

I found a answer.

(row1.deptime.equals("NA")) ?  "" : row1.deptime